# How do use "changeset" in Jenkinsfile in dynamically generated steps?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile which as one of its stages builds several Docker images and pushes them to a registry. There is quite a long and growing list of these images, so I don't want to repetitively declare the build. Instead, I have a variable:

```
def dockerImages = ["myimage1","myimage2","myimage3"]
```

And then have the following stage:

```
stage("Initiate docker image builds") {
    steps {
        script {
            dockerImages.each { image ->
                stage ("${image}") {
                    utils.doStuff(${image}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I only want build to happen when there is a change, so I could do something like:

```
stage("Initiate docker image builds") {
    when{ 
          changeset "dockerfiles/**"
    }    
    steps {
        script {
            dockerImages.each { image ->
                stage ("${image}") {
                    utils.doStuff(${image}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this would trigger building **all** the images if there was a change on just one of them. Is there a way that I could modify my script to have the `when` apply to the inner `stage ("${image}"` section? The syntax doesn't appear to allow `when` on that level.

Comment: Changesets is what has changed from a previous build to this one. If e.g. a previous build was cancelled and restarted, the changeset would be empty. This may not be what you want, as in this case the new images would never be built.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, I don't know of any better alternative though

Comment: We run "git diff" with base branch and parse the output of that.

Comment: Alternatively, you could setup parallel stages dynamically generated from the list of Docker images, and use a `when` expression for each of the stages. This would also be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the Changeset to see what files have changed e.g.
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-58441

Looks quite messy code though.

Could also break the dockerfiles out to their own repos.  It might seem "wasteful" having a repo for a single file, but it totally removes situations like this.

Or have separate Jenkinsfiles and jenkins jobs for each container build which just look it its Dockerfile has changed.  Would need a lot of executors though if you had lots of containers